# Update jquery for newer - jquery.com website down

Tags: jquery

I would like to update my jquery to newer.

Where is other jquery mirror that i can refer?

I would like `updated files for 1.6.3`

Answer (score 1):

Try copying from Google CDN or Microsoft CDN.

`Google jQuery Libraries:`

- https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

`Microsoft jQuery Libraries:`

- http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0